# Using the 'U' Matrix of SVD as Feature Reduction

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd

This is a follow-up to the question asked regarding SVD and dimensionality reduction ([question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64370/how-to-use-svd-for-dimensionality-reduction)).

In that question I asked how to use SVD for dimensionality reduction. Although not stated, the ultimate goal here is to use the reduced feature set and input them into a classification or regression algorithm.

I have learned that SVD is a technique used by `prcomp` in R, as the "v" matrix from a run of svd on a centered and scaled matrix is the same as the loadings (eigen vectors) from a PCA using the traditional eigen decomposition on a correlation matrix:

```
data(iris)

#these two match
eigen(cor(iris[,-5])) #eigen vectors
svd(scale(iris[,-5]))$v
```

This has helped with my understanding of the connection between SVD and PCA. However, I have two additional questions:

1) Why do the following differ in signs for the first PC? Is this OK?

```
svd(cor(iris[,-5]))$u
svd(scale(iris[,-5]))$v
```

2) To match the output of prcomp, one can multiply the scaled/centered original data by the 'v' matrix from SVD:

```
PCSCORE1<-scale(iris[,-5]) %*% SVD2$v[,1:2]  #PC scores from SVD
PCSCORE1[1:10,]  #PC scores from first 2 PC

#matches this
PCA<-prcomp(iris[,-5], center = TRUE, scale =TRUE) 
PCA$x[1:10,1:2]
```

but I have seen in multiple locations (e.g. [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/dimensionality-reduction-svd-or-pca-on-a-large-sparse-matrix?rq=1)) and the rapidminer package (a machine learning tool written in JAVA) that just the 'u' matrix that results from running svd on the center/scaled input matrix X is used as the PC scores.

*What is the connection of u to X*v and if u can be used, why does prcomp compute X*v?* Mechanically u is X*v*diag(1/d) so the eigen vectors related to the largest eigen values are scaled down - why is this used?

Comment: Question (1) is answered in several places, including http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/im-getting-jumpy-loadings-in-rollapply-pca-in-r-can-i-fix-it.

Comment: Best I have found in multiple statements (other questions) that the solutions are not unique and thus signs can flip. I guess that explains this - although I read those more as explaining differences in software.

Comment: It can help to think about this geometrically. Principal components are *lines* without direction. The software outputs *vectors* to describe those lines. Literally *any* nonzero vector on a line will suffice, but typically only vectors of unit length are used--of which there are, of course, two. Furthermore, in (rare) cases there are two or more principal lines with the same eigenvalue. They generate entire *planes* (or higher dimensional linear subspaces) of "principal components." This creates even more ways to represent the answer--you can rotate the vectors in these planes.

Answer (score 2):

My (very limited) understanding is that u (left singular vectors) measures aspects of the rows of your matrix, and v (right singular vectors) measures aspects of the columns.  So u can be used to measure similarity between rows, and v can be used to measure similarity between columns. If you multiply u and v, you get back an approximation of the original data matrix (this is how recommender engines work).

I would think you could use `u` as well as `x %*% v` as features in a learning algorithm.

Comment: I think your interpretation of u and v are correct - certainly aligns with my understanding of LSI. I am not completely clear on why scaling x %*% v by the reciprocal of d makes any intuitive sense? I guess perhaps it accentuates the PC scores that have smaller variance this way?

Comment: @B_Miner I've never seen a good theoretical reason to add the eigenvalues into the calculation, but I've seen it improve predictive models, so I try it sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, say you have a data matrix $X$ and it is $20$ x $1000$. Here, we have $20,000$ variables to keep track of and store/use.

Let us say you perform svd on your data matrix, such that:

$$
X = USV^H
$$

Then, $U$ is a $20$ x $20$ matrix, $S$ is a $20$ x $1000$ matrix, and $V$ is a $1000$ x $1000$ matrix.

Now let us say you want to represent your data matrix more compactly. You inspect the diagonal elecment of $S$, and you decide you want to keep only the first two singular values/vectors, because the first two singular values are very very large relative to all the rest.

So now your compact data matrix, call it $X_{new}$, is made of the first two columns of $U$, the first two column/rows of $S$, and the first two columns of $V$.

But do you need to keep track of $20,000$ variables any more? No. You can just keep track of the first two columns of $U$, (20*2 = 40 numbers) the first two singular values of $S$, (2 numbers), and the first two columns of $V$, (1000 * 2 = 2000 numbers).

So now the total number of variables you need to keep track of / use / store / input into a classifier is: 40 + 2 + 2000 = 2042. Before this, you have to feed your classifier 20,000 variables. Now, you can feed it just 2042.

This is how I understand DR to work for classification.