# Using SVD as feature for recognition of hand writing images

Tags: r, classification, pattern-recognition, image-processing, svd

For images of small letters a..z with dimension 12x12 gray level, there are  144 feature (pixel values) and limited data set.

I want to use the single value Decomposition SVD  as a feature which may help in enhancing recognition.

I reached the post [Using the 'U' Matrix of SVD as Feature Reduction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64641/126844).
The post  suggest of using the first two columns of U, the first two column/rows of d, and the first two columns of V.

So, for the image 12x12, I get 24+24+2= 50 feature per image.

Is that a proven solution as a feature or I have to use the 144 pixel value as a feature?