# Truncated SVD: how do I go from [Uk, Sk, Vk'] to low-dimension matrix?

Tags: svd

I have a large word-frequency matrix (~6m unique words X ~4k documents) and I'm trying to use truncated singular value decomposition (SVD) to project it onto a matrix with fewer dimensions. I know how to get to $[U_{k}, S_{k}, V_{k}']$, but I don't know what to do then.

Each tutorial I find gives me a different answer. [Here](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi4107/LSI.pdf), for instance, I'm told to retain only the first $k$ rows of $S_{k}$ and $V_{k}'$ and then multiply $S_{k}V_{k}'$. In the scikit-learn implementation, however, they do it by multiplying $U_{k}S_{k}'$ ([formula](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#truncated-singular-value-decomposition-and-latent-semantic-analysis) and [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/truncated_svd.py)). (The [book chapter they mention](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/18lsi.pdf) as source doesn't say anything about that.) In [this previous answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57467/how-to-perform-dimension-reduction-after-doing-pca-in-r) they suggest $X'U_{k}$ instead (though they are talking about PCA, so maybe that doesn't apply here). Other answers haven't helped ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64370/how-to-use-svd-for-dimensionality-reduction), for instance, they say we need to apply truncated SVD to the reduced matrix - which doesn't sound right, we use truncated SVD precisely to get to the reduced matrix, no?).

So, bottom line: how do I go from $[U_{k}, S_{k}, V_{k}']$ to a reduced data matrix? Which of the above formulas is the correct one (and why)?

Just to be clear: I'm not looking to reduce rank only (that I can do by multiplying $U_{k}S_{k}V_{k}'$ but it gives me the exact same dimensions I had before, which doesn't help me); I want to reduce the actual dimensions of the data matrix.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have 4x2 X matrix, run SVD and get U,S,V:

- U is 4x4
- S is 4x2, where only the top 2x2 is not empty
- V is 2x2

If you want to truncate to a single largest singular value:

- remove all columns from U leaving only the first one, now U1 is 4x1
- remove all columns from S leaving only the first one, now S1 is 1x1
- remove all columns from V leaving only the first one, now V1 is 2x1

You can restore the X matrix by U1*S1*V1'

The dimensionality is greatly reduced because now you can use 4x1 U matrix instead of original 4x2 X matrix.

UPDATE: you also have neat equality: X*V=U*S, so you could use both X*V1 or U1*S1 as your reduced dimension matrices, or simply U1, which is similar to the score in PCA

Comment: That's it then? I simply get U1 and use it instead of X? But then why do some tutorials suggest more complicated formulas, like $S_{k}V_{k}'$, $U_{k}S_{k}'$, and $X'U_{k}$? Or are all of these valid answers but somehow different in their properties? Could you point me in the direction of a book/tutorial/paper that explains why U1 works?

Comment: look at this [PCA vs SVD](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/picasso/mats/PCA-Tutorial-Intuition_jp.pdf) tutorial, it explains how to estimate PCA through SVD. PCA may seem more intuitive for some people. It also discusses the dimensionality reduction